# How to upload images with url with tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, tinymce

I am creating a blog using mongoose/express/mongodb. When I upload an image with tinyMCE to my blog and enter the source the image does not appear on my blog. The alt appears upon inspection but the source does not. Does tinyMCE allow url image upload or only local upload? If it does allow it how can I make the source upload?

Code for create route

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <!-- use TINYMCE for textarea -->
                    <label for="blogContent">Blog Content</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="blog[body]" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10" type="hidden"></textarea>
                </div>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 500,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  styleselect | bold italic backcolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | image link | removeformat | help',
    });
    </script>
```

[Here is me entering a photo locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFK46.png)

[Here is the local photo populating in tinyMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyOYH.png)

[Here is the front end of the blog with no image appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpaQW.png)

[Here is the database entry in mlab missing the src attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHEqm.png)

Comment: Have you set a public static directory to serve images/js/etc?

Comment: No, I did not know that was a thing.

Comment: I wrote you an answer, lets see that works on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to setup and serve static files. Take a look at this URL for more information:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

First create a directory called 'public' in your root directory, then use this code in express:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

You can then link to the uploaded images via:

http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg

In your case, you may need to set the directory of your static folder to where ever tinyMCE puts it. That being said, I personally would always put it in the public directory just out of habit.

Comment: Could this also be the reason when I create a link, that the url doesnt populate for the href?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? I can't really help further unless you give more information such as code. - But putting this code into your file should take a few minutes maximum =)

Comment: Ok i implemented what you said and I still cannot get the image to appear.

Comment: Can you put a random image into the public directory, and then try to access it via URL? Let's test that you implemented it correctly first. And then it will be much easier to figure out why tinyMCE isn't working.

Comment: Ok I updated my question and provided photos to help you see my issue.

Comment: Also if you need any more info that I'm not providing please let me know as I am very new to this